# Set request attribute using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have the following code:

```
<bean:define id="hasDocuments" name="BudgetSimulationDetailForm" property="hasDocuments" type="java.lang.Boolean"/> 
<%
    request.setAttribute("enablebtnRelatedDocs", "true"); 
    request.setAttribute("hasDocuments", String.valueOf(hasDocuments));
%>
```

I want to remove the scriptlet, I tried using c:set with different scopes but it didn't work. 
Is it possible to set a request attribute using JSTL tags?

I tried this and did not work:

```
<c:set name="enablebtnRelatedDocs" value="true" scope="request"/>
```

and also

```
<c:set name="enablebtnRelatedDocs" value="${true}" scope="request"/>
```

Afterwards there is an include:

```
<jsp:include page="/gema/jsp/includes/detail/top_Detail.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="title_key" value="${title}" />
    <jsp:param name="title_bundle" value="buc" />           
    <jsp:param name="standard_buttons_include" value="true" />
    <jsp:param name="typeId" value="53555" />
    <jsp:param name="detail" value="budget" />
</jsp:include>
```

Inside the included JSP the request attribute is not visible, apparently.

Comment: `c:set` should work fine. Show us what you tried.

Comment: And what does that do? Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Inside top_Detail.jsp there is a scriplet that reads request.getParameter and request.getAttribute and both return null.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds Good, You want to use [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/) instead of Scriplet.

Yes, It's possible using `c:set`. Read more about [Core Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html)

```
<c:set var="enablebtnRelatedDocs" value="${true}" scope="request"/>

<c:out value="${requestScope.enablebtnRelatedDocs }"/>
```

By default `c:set` set a attribute in *page context*. you can set it in any scope.

Comment: I tried with value="${true}" instead of value="true" with same result.

Comment: how are you accessing it inside the included JSP page?

Comment: It works with `<jsp:include>` as well. Try `<c:import url="/other.jsp"/>` Access it as I suggest in my post. Or you can set it in `session` scope as well.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the JSTL Core library function "set" accepts the following attributes:

JSTL Core set property (credits to tutorialspoint.com) : 
value,
target,
property,
var,
scope

You should use "var=" instead of "name=". Hope this helps!

Happy coding!
  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUuTH.png): [image]

Comment: Please don't post text in images